# Что означает структура, содержащая в себе свой тип как переменную?

Tags: c++, структуры

```
struct Node

{ int d;    

Node *left//; что означает эта запись?

};
```

Чем является Node *left, если это часть структуры?

Comment: "Чем является Node *left" - указателем на аналогичную структуру.

Comment: классическая структура для реализации связанного списка.

Comment: Она содержит не свой тип, а тип `Node *`